# How to write a simple test case for Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How would I write a simple unit test for this:

http://server_ip:port_number/api/v1/package/

This is my setup:

**models.py**

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ('name',)
```

**views.py**

```
class PackageViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'name'
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'package', views.PackageViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```